# Remove from a string all except selected characters

Tags: regex, r, gdata

I want to remove from a string all characters that are not digits, minus signs, or decimal points.

I imported data from Excel using `read.xls`, which include some strange characters. I need to convert these to numeric. I am not too familiar with regular expressions, so need a simpler way to do the following:

```
excel_coords <- c(" 19.53380Ý°", " 20.02591°", "-155.91059°", "-155.8154Â°")
unwanted <- unique(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[0-9]|\\.|-", "", excel_coords), "")))
clean_coords <- gsub(do.call("paste", args = c(as.list(unwanted), sep="|")), 
                     replacement = "", x = excel_coords)

> clean_coords
[1] "19.53380"   "20.02591"   "-155.91059" "-155.8154"
```

Bonus if somebody can tell me why these characters have appeared in some of my data (the degree signs are part of the original Excel worksheet, but the others are not).

Comment: why can't you just do a simple find and replace before loading the data? If the data is in excel, try forcing the data to be decimals. Also, seems like you've already got a solution that works too.

Comment: @blunders: it seems like such a simple task that I hoped would already exist in regexp so it's something of a learning question. But also, I am giving this to someone who needs it to work on an Excel worksheet with degree signs (which force the cells to be text not numeric).

Comment: The Y and A are there as encoding artifacts, UTF8 text improperly encoded to another codepage.

Comment: A similar question was answered today on r-help. See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Extract-number-from-string-tp3264340p3264359.html

Comment: The answer on r-help applies here with appropriate change in the regular expressions:  `"[^-.0-9]"` instead of `"\\D"` and `"[-.0-9]+"` instead of `"\\d+"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short and sweet. Thanks to comment by G. Grothendieck.

```
gsub("[^-.0-9]", "", excel_coords)
```

From http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html: "A character class is a list of characters enclosed between [ and ] which matches any single character in that list; unless the first character of the list is the caret ^, when it matches any character not in the list."

Comment: That is sweet. I tried something similar but mistakenly thought that the "." and maybe even the "-" would need to be escaped. I guess not.

Comment: @DWin : it's in the help files on regex. Tough sandwich to eat, but delicious nonetheless.

Comment: Tough? Yes. Useful? Extremely. Delicious, er , ummm , sensible people may differ. I suspect the relevant sentences are those following: "Most metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class."

Answer (score 2):

Can also be done by using `strsplit`, `sapply` and `paste` and by indexing the correct characters rather than the wrong ones:

```
 excel_coords <- c(" 19.53380Ý°", " 20.02591°", "-155.91059°", "-155.8154Â°")
 correct_chars <- c(0:9,"-",".")
 sapply(strsplit(excel_coords,""), 
          function(x)paste(x[x%in%correct_chars],collapse=""))

[1] "19.53380"   "20.02591"   "-155.91059" "-155.8154"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(.+)([[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+)(.+)", "\\2", excel_coords)
[1] "9.53380" "0.02591" "5.91059" "5.8154"
```

Comment: Almost, but you've chopped off my leading digits and minus signs. But I get the idea now.

Comment: `gsub("(\\s*)(-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)(.+)", "\\2", excel_coords)`

Comment: ooops. I can see where I was loosing "-" but not where I lost the leading digits.